# How to uninstall an indirect dependency

Tags: node.js, npm, mapnik

I am troubleshotting the installation of a node application and I am running into an error that was solved before here: https://github.com/mapnik/node-mapnik/issues/899
Basically, I have two versions of mapnik installed and it is giving me the error. Then, I have to uninstall an indirect dependency (a dependency of a dependency that is required in my app).

I`ve tried some variations of npm uninstall and updating the direct dependency in my package.json but it did not work.

```
$ npm ls mapnik
irio@0.0.1 /home/ubr1/irio
├── mapnik@4.2.1 
└─┬ tilelive-mapnik@0.6.18
  └── mapnik@3.7.2
```

I have to uninstall the mapnik@3.7.2. How can I do it?

Comment: delete the folder & edit the package-lock.json ?

Comment: Thanks for answering @Marc. In the node_modules/tilelive/node_modules there is no mapnik dependency.

Comment: I was looking in the wrong directory. Now I`ve could delete from package.json and run npm upgrade. Thanks @Marc